# Using Terminal for FTP connect with MAC

Tags: mac, terminal, ftp

I am simply trying to copy a folder and rename it in the same directory

Attempted: cp -rfp folder folder-7-03

Terminal Reply: Invalid Request

I don't use terminal often as my FTP App is quite good. Thought I would have a go at it and now I see why I was always discouraged. Still, I would like to know since I realize the power of Terminal.

Please review the status if it's helpful here:

> Connected and logged into saidwebsite.com.
>
> No proxy connection.
>
> Gate ftp: off, server (none), port ftpgate.
>
> Passive mode: on; fallback to active mode: on.
>
> Mode: stream; Type: binary; Form: non-print; Structure: file.
>
> Verbose: on; Bell: off; Prompting: on; Globbing: on.
>
> Store unique: off; Receive unique: off.
>
> Preserve modification times: on.
>
> Case: off; CR stripping: on.
>
> Ntrans: off.
>
> Nmap: off.
>
> Hash mark printing: off; Mark count: 1024; Progress bar: on.
>
> Get transfer rate throttle: off; maximum: 0; increment 1024.
>
> Put transfer rate throttle: off; maximum: 0; increment 1024.
>
> Socket buffer sizes: send 131070, receive 262140.
>
> Use of PORT cmds: on.
>
> Use of EPSV/EPRT cmds for IPv4: on.
>
> Command line editing: on.
>
> Version: tnftp 20070806

Thanks for any insight on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have folder on FTP server full of files (not subfolders).
Create folder in your current dir that you want to rename:

```
mkdir test
```

get files with `wget`

```
cd test/ && wget ftp://user:pass@FTPserverIP/path/to/test/*
```

leave test folder `cd ..` and rename folder localy:

```
mv test/ testnew
```

then use [`wput`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wput) to copy folder and files to ftp server:

```
wput testnew/* ftp://user:pass@FTPserverIP/path/to/test/parent/
```

This works on my Linux (Ubuntu) box, Mac should have `wget` but `wput` you might need to install.

Hope it helps,
Mirko

Comment: Well that definitely got me a bit further thanks! Now, it's telling me there is no such file or directory which is not the case. I've entered the command ! dir and see the file I need to Duplicate.

Comment: does it have some spaces or special characters in name? you have to escape them with `\<char> `

Comment: sorry took so long to get back here. Caught up with a project. So there are no spaces or special characters going on here. Sounds like some freak occurrence that only I seem to be able to produce. This kind of thing happens to me all too often...

Comment: so, i've tried to make a copy of the public_html folder in cpanel and it comes back with "No such file or directory". I am in the root folder and checked the folder to see if public_html was in it using "ls" and it shows up. Why would it not find the file or directory?

Comment: I changed the answer after full understanding the problem, still I haven't used Mac a lot, but that should work. Let me know how it goes